# shiny fix position of collapsible panel

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make this shiny app have a collapsible panel fixed at the top. But, whenever I make the position fixed, the collapse functionality doesn't work.

What do I have to do to fix this collapsible panel on top?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4),
    column(4,
      div(
        bsCollapse(id = "cntrlC1", open = "Panel 2",
          bsCollapsePanel("Control Panel", 
            htmlOutput("dateSelector", inline = TRUE),
            style = "info"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DTOutput('sampleTbl')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dateSelector <- renderUI({
    airDatepickerInput(
      "dateSelector",
      label = "Select Start & End Dates",
      value = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-10"),
      multiple = 2
    )
  })
  output$sampleTbl <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
    data <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 100), B = rep(2, 100), C = rep(3, 100))
    m <- datatable(
        data,
        options = list(pageLength = 100)
    )
    m 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4),
    column(4,
           div(
             bsCollapse(id = "cntrlC1", open = "Panel 2",
                        bsCollapsePanel("Control Panel", 
                                        htmlOutput("dateSelector", inline = TRUE),
                                        style = "info"
                        )
             ), style="position:fixed;"
           )
  )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width=2, textInput("searchField1", "Search")),
    column(width=2, uiOutput("saveText1"), actionButton("saveBtn1", "Save"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    DTOutput('sampleTbl')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dateSelector <- renderUI({
    airDatepickerInput(
      "dateSelector",
      label = "Select Start & End Dates",
      value = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-10"),
      multiple = 2
    )
  })
  output$sampleTbl <- DT::renderDT(server = TRUE, {
    data <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 100), B = rep(2, 100), C = rep(3, 100))
    m <- datatable(
      data,
      options = list(pageLength = 100)
    )
    m 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: The issue is that the normal behavior is if you open the control panel, the search and save button move down dynamically. When the control panel is closed, the search bar and button move back up.  In your example, we lose that functionality. No point in having a collapse panel if you cant use the space. Meaning, you moved the search bar down, and now if control panel is open it is just empty space.

Comment: But position no longer fixed. If there is content on page where you have to scroll down, the control panel will no longer be in view.

Comment: Please uncomment the `style="position:fixed;"` part.  Code is updated.

Comment: I updated my example. Without position:fixed you can see the data table move down. With position:fixed, it breaks the functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your desired output.  For me with or without position:fixed, expected output is displayed.